# Converting an array of json objects to a 'readable' string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an array of json objects, like so:

```
 [
  {id: "81238651", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"},
  {id: "89581097", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"}
 ]
```

The goal is to get something that can be pretty-printed on the screen or to a log, such as a final string that reads like:

```
 'id: '81238651', secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"\n
 id: '89581097', secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"'
```

While I can loop over the array and use JSON.stringify() to put something together I was wondering if there were more sophisticated tools / packages that can assist in destructuring and prettifying things?

Comment: Are you looking for a recognized package that people use? Or just a terse way of managing it?

Comment: I was wondering / hoping there was a package that assisted, but your snippet is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy readable code:

```js
const arr = [
  {id: "81238651", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"},
  {id: "89581097", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"}
]

let finalStr = '';

for(let obj of arr) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    finalStr += String(key + ': ' + obj[key] + ', ');
  });
  finalStr += '\n';
}

console.log(finalStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will format is out, can change out the pattern how you like.

```js
const rawObjects =  [
  {id: "81238651", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"},
  {id: "89581097", secondary_id: "P2087N", count: "2"}
 ];
 
const formatted = rawObjects.map(o => Object.keys(o)
                            .reduce((a, v, i) => a + `${v}: ${o[v]}${(i<Object.keys(o).length-1)?', ' : ''}`, ''))
                            .join('\n');

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Obviously this is not fancy, could add recursion on objects etc.